# how to close unity3d editor from command line

Tags: c#, git, shell, unity-game-engine

Hello i am trying to run unity test runner test cases from command line using the command `>Unity.exe -runTests -projectPath PATH_TO_YOUR_PROJECT -testResults C:\temp\results.xml -testPlatform playmode`

resource: https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/testing-editortestsrunner.html

But the problem here is the above is launching the unity again with given project path. In my case most of the times the Project will be already open in unity editor and its trowing error `Another instance of unity editor is running with same project`.

I wanted to close the running unity instance by saving the changes in scene. Or is there any way to run the test cases with out launching new instance from command line.

I am using command line because I am executing these commands in git hook

Thanks

Comment: So it seems that the real problem is "How to force running tests for a Unity project with git hook?" Very interesting, I have never thought about it before. If you just want to run unit tests I would suggest running tests via NUnits instead, but I see it from your command that you want the tests to run in playmode...

Comment: Since IMO it is not possible to execute a script in a Unity project without opening it with Unity editor, how about not to directly force a test with git hook?
Instead, in the editor you can starts a service that monitors the project status about if something has changed (maybe uses git?) and if the tests are run after the changes are observed, and the service continuously logs the project status to a file that will be checked by your git hook. 
Although you cannot run tests automatically when commit/push, but at least you ensures tests are run when you try to commit/push.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using shell on Windows, you can try the below to close the unity process. There might be analogous way to achieve the same on another platform.

`taskkill /IM "C:\Program Files\Unity_SomeVersionCode\Editor\Unity.exe"`